# Drawing only one triangle with RegularPolyCollection. Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've drawn three circles using CircleCollection and I want to plot only one triangle using RegularPolyCollection. My triangle's vertices are:

**vertices = [2, 1], [8, 1], [5, 9]**

I don't understand the options sizes, offsets and transoffset because my english is very poor, and I've only seen examples with random vertices, and for that reason is very complicated to find out points by hand.
I think **sizes** is the area of the external circumference of my triangle, but what are **offsets**?
Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import collections, transforms
import math as math

__author__ = 'Tobal'


def triangular(n):
    return n * (n + 1) / 2


def draw_triangular(n):
    fig = plt.gcf()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
    vertices = [2, 1], [8, 1], [5, 9]
    area = math.pi * .2 ** 2 * 500

    '''circle1 = plt.Circle(vertices[0], .2, color='b')
    circle2 = plt.Circle(vertices[1], .2, color='b')
    circle3 = plt.Circle(vertices[2], .2, color='b')
    fig.gca().add_artist(circle1)
    fig.gca().add_artist(circle2)
    fig.gca().add_artist(circle3)'''

    circles = collections.CircleCollection([area, area, area], offsets=vertices, transOffset=ax.transData)
    trans = fig.dpi_scale_trans + transforms.Affine2D().scale(1.0/72.0)
    circles.set_transform(trans)  # the points to pixels transform

    poly = patches.Polygon(vertices)
    poly2 = collections.RegularPolyCollection(numsides=3, sizes=(math.pi * 5.5 ** 2 * 500, ), offsets=[5, 1],
                                              edgecolors=('black', ), facecolors=('red', ), transOffset=ax.transData,
                                              rotation=0)
    poly2.set_transform(trans)

    #ax.add_patch(poly)
    ax.add_collection(poly2, autolim=True)
    ax.add_collection(circles, autolim=True)
    #poly.set_color('red')
    circles.set_color(['blue'])
    ax.autoscale_view()
    ax.set_title('Números Triangulares')

    plt.show()


print(triangular(5))
draw_triangular(2)
```

First, I used patch, but the circles appear below triangle vertices, for that reason I've thought to use collections to plot my triangle.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool. `RegularPolyCollection` may only contain regular triangles (equilateral triangles, all angles 60°).

If you just want to draw a single triangle as a collection, you should use the `collections.PolyCollection`:

```
pc = collections.PolyCollection((vertices,))
ax.add_collection(pc)
```

However, if you are happy with the simple patch, but the drawing order is wrong, use the `zorder` keyword when creating the patch. See: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html for the ideas behind Z order.

Comment: Ok, zorder is available with collections, too